# get_category_parents displays an empty category

Tags: categories

When I execute

```
'<?php echo get_category_parents(get_query_var('cat'), false, '\' - \''); ?>'
```

on the category page `bar`, which is a sub category of `foo`, this is the output: `'foo' - 'bar' - ''`. How do I remove the last, empty category without PHP functions like `explode` or `substr`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I remove the last, empty category without PHP functions like
>   `explode` or `substr`?

You don't. Look at the source: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/category-template.php#L42 The output you see is intended behavior and there is no filter. My guess is that you are trying to use the function for something it is not meant for.

You could take another approach and use `get_ancestors` or `wp_list_categories` but `substr` or `str_replace` would be the easiest.